# vs2019 model builder uses azure for image recognition does vs2022 also use azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I know you need azure for vs2019 image recognition but does vs2022 also use azure. I cant find any documentation on this

Answer (score 0):

The same vs2019 object recognition tutorial do work for vs2022.

[image]
[image]

Here is a [sample tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/train-image-classification-model-azure-mlnet-model-builder/) you can refer to which works for vs2019 or later.

As an alternative Image Analysis can be also done in [Microsoft Computer Vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) algorithms that can analyze visual content in different ways based on inputs and user choices.

Comment: I would line to detect objects in images( I dont need to bounding boxes) and azure can get pretty pricey and would like to see if there is an option to use my local machine

Comment: @Tate Like already mentioned you can use [Computer Vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) for Object detection, Image Categorization, Face detection and many more. Try checking this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/image-analysis-client-library?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=visual-studio)